# How to render Data when paginating pages

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework

I was making a blog app --web . I added some pagination and filtering. Now I will use JavaScript to render the posts I get from my API to the page.

So, Do i have to create a specific div for every page and only show one div -- the page that is active-- so when user goes back to the page, I don't have to make API call again. Or when user visits the page he has already visited, do I have to get the data again and then render it, or if I have to cache it. If yes, please suggest the ways I have to do it.

My API Code

```
class HomePageAPIView(ListAPIView):
queryset = Post.objects.all()
serializer_class = PostSerilizer
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
filter_backends = [SearchFilter,OrderingFilter]
ordering_fields = ['posted',]
search_fields = ['key_words','author__username',]
print(pagination_class)
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is a frontend issue and not related with django-rest-framework. Can you provide more details regarding the frontend framework that you are using?

Comment: I prorammmed the app now